# Want to validate the user on a button click for ipaddress field using jquery input mask plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, mask

I am using jquery mask plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

i want to validate the field ipaddress if the user enter `192.3.4.` and forgot to put value after `.` then i want to validate the text input box then when the user click on the save button

Here is my Html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ip_address" placeholder="*IP Address">
```

and here is my jquery for the plugin mask

```
$('.ip_address').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', {
       translation: {
                      'Z': {
                            pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true
                           }
                  }
});
```

and here is how i want to validate the user on burron click

```
$('.btnsaveForm').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                     var ip = $('.ip_address').val();
                     if(ip){
                        alert('ip address');
                     }else{
                        alert('not an ip address');
                     }


            });
```

Kindly help me Thanks

Comment: just want to explain the  if(ip) the ip address format is true then show success message other wise  show error message

Answer (score 1):

You may try a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as below.

```
$('.btnsaveForm').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ip = $('.ip_address').val();
    if(/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/.test(ip)) {
        alert('valid ip address');
    }else{
        alert('not an ip address');
    }
});
```

- `\d+` => match numbers only
- `\.` => match a `.`
- `^` => input start point
- `$` => input end point

**Edit:** You may write a basic plugin like below.

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.isIpv4 = function() {
        return /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/.test( $(this).val() );
    };    
}( jQuery ));
```

Use it as:

```
var ip = $('.ip_address'); // no val() here!
if( ip.isIpv4() ) {
    alert('valid ip address');
}
```

**Edit:** As per your last comment, you would be better off using a function like below as a `jQuery` plugin is *not* meant for this.

```
function isIpv4(ip) {
    return /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/.test(ip);
}

var ipAdd = $('.ip_address').val();
if( isIpv4(ipAdd) ) {
    alert('valid ip address');
}
```

Comment: @Ishettyl can you kindly provide me the plugin solution if you have any it will be so help full this regex is working but i want to prefer the plugin solution. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks kindly let me test it

Comment: @Ishettyl  if i want to pass value to the isIpv4() using $('.ip_address').val(); how can i do that can you please help me